# Recursion in Asp.Net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, recursion, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to make a tree structured product category view. I have found [this article by Ole Michelsen](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/mapping-relational-table-data-to-a-tree-structure-in-mvc.html) from 2011, which I think looks promising. The article describes a method similar to what I almost had in mind, using Razor to recursively render the tree structure.

My database table is almost identical to the one described in the article:

```
[ProductCategory]
Id
ParentId
Title
```

I'm not sure what my view model should look like. Should it be an `IEnumerable` of ProductCategory, or should it be an instance of ProductCategory and have an `IEnumerable` of ProductCategories in it?

Something like this ...

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int NumOfProducts { get; set; }
}
```

... or more like this?

```
public class ViewModelProductCategory
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductCategory> ProductCategory { get; set; }
    //public int NumOfProducts { get; set; }//<--Not too sure about this property
    public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

If the second one is closer to the "correct" one, how can I have SortOrder and NumOfProducts (how many products are in the current category)?

And the thing I'm most confused about, is how the razor rendering comes together. How do I send the viewmodel to the recursive partial view, and how does the partial view know which item to render?

I have some razor-code, but I can guarantee that posting it will NOT make anything clearer as of what I'm trying to achieve.

This pseudo-code is perhaps more describing:

```
_recursivePartial.cshtml
@model [my unknown viewmodel goes here, is it IEnumerable or not?]
<ul>
foreach item in model
{
    <li>@Html.Partial("_recursivePartial.cshtml", [what goes here?])
    // 1: How does _recursivePartial.cshtml know where in the tree it is?
    // 2: How does this structure relate to the data structure in the DB?
}
</ul>
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components - I'm on the same mission

Answer (score 2):

I’m not sure there is a “correct” way of doing things, but I like to keep my database models different to the view models. I often use [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org) to get the data between models.

In your situation I’d probably have two View Models:

```
public class ProductCategoryItemModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    public int NumOfProducts { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ProductCategoriesModel
{
    public List<ProductCategoryItemModel> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

I always convert ToList() rather than passing an IEnumerable to views, but again I’m not sure that’s the “correct” way.